# Vectorized vs non-vectorized for loop efficiency

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to write a simple for loop that rank items in a dataframe based on how new they are (in a random range).

The code below works fine but from what I understand about R (currently learning R), this probably isn't very scalable or using R's most powerful features. It may require more criterion too, further slowing it down

Is this the best way to go about looping over rows in a dataframe and if not how would I go about vectorising this?

My data looks like this,

```
   Product_ID  Product_Created Price_GBP shoprank       absdate
1          19 09/09/2010 04:38        50      135 3723.495 days
2          20 09/09/2010 04:44        50       19 3723.495 days
3          39 09/09/2010 04:58        50      117 3723.495 days
4          40 09/09/2010 05:03        50       68 3723.495 days
5       21957 15/10/2010 02:48      1250       21 3687.495 days
6           8 01/04/2011 17:50       149      137 3519.495 days
7           9 12/04/2011 18:18       120       55 3508.495 days
8        5647 25/04/2011 20:01       300       73 3495.495 days
9        1178 28/04/2011 10:09       450       55 3492.495 days
10         11 28/04/2011 15:32       410      141 3492.495 days
```

I'm calculating absdate like this,

```
safeproducts$absdate <- difftime(Sys.time(), safeproducts$Product_Created,,units = ("days"))
```

And my for loop,

```
for (i in 1:nrow(safeproducts)){
  if (safeproducts$absdate[i] <= 30) {
    safeproducts$shoprank[i] <- sample(1:300,1)
  } else if (safeproducts$absdate[i] > 30 & safeproducts$absdate[i] <= 180){
    safeproducts$shoprank[i] <- sample(1:330,1)
  } else if (safeproducts$absdate[i] > 180) {
    safeproducts$shoprank[i] <- sample(1:150,1)
  }
}
```

As I mentioned, i'm currently learning R so any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you put a reproducible example of your data into the question please? Just post the output of `dput(safeproducts)`.

Comment: By the way, are you really really sure, you want to use `sample()` here? I'm wondering what your goal is.

Comment: I'm trying to give each product a random number in a given interval based on their age in days, planning to do this with price as well to generate some sort of 'rank' with a bit of random noise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I don't know what your loop is supposed to do, but here's a much more dense version using the `tidverse` packages.

```
library(tidyverse)

safeproducts %>%
    mutate(absdate_class = case_when(absdate <= 30 ~ 300
                                     , absdate <= 180 ~ 330
                                     , TRUE ~ 150)) %>%
    group_by(absdate_class) %>%
    mutate(shoprank = sample.int(first(absdate_class), n(), replace = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-absdate_class)
```

Read the pipe symbol (`%>%`) as "then", like 'take the dataframe' **then** 'calculate the variable `absdate_class` and so on. Reading this [book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) will help a lot.

Generally on `for` loops. Avoid them, whenever you can in `R`. The only real scenario where you want to use a `for` loop in R is when iteration `i` of the loop needs the result of iteration `i-1`.

Happy learning. :)

Comment: Could put the `sample` inside case_when, no need for group by, etc

Comment: Not that important but I think importing only `dplyr` would be sufficient as opposed to the entire `tidyverse`.

Comment: Calling `sample()` inside `case_when()`: That's true. I didn't run the code, but my guess is that this would be much slower on big dataset. Let's say you have a million rows, than you would call `sample()` a million times instead of 3 times. My guess is that this would be very slow. But like I said - didn't try it.